# How creating file in the directory of the project

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat6, filewriter

in the tomcat6 server I have a project that contains a servlet,

I called in a servlet:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
out.write("text text text");
out.close();
```

it creates the file in the directory of eclipse.exe cons I want them to create in the directory of the project.

how do

Comment: Are you well aware that such a file would then get lost on every redeploy of the WAR in production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Servlet:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/filename.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
```

Note: It will work when you will deploy it in tomcat and run from out side eclipse.
As eclipse has its own internal structure when it deploy the web application.

To check differnce put

`System.out.println("File Path: " + path);` in your servlet.